# Centos 7 yum update issue

Tags: linux, centos, operating-systems, centos-7, yum

I am getting the below error while doing the "yum update" in centos7. I tried all other ways to fix but nothing is working. Please find the below full error for your information.

Please find below the error while we doing the yum update on the centos7 server and same perl-DBD was installed in the other server but in that server, we have not encountered this issue all working fine, that also same centos7

````
Error: Package: libreport-2.1.11-53.el7.centos.i686 (base)
Requires: libreport-filesystem = 2.1.11-53.el7.centos
Removing: libreport-filesystem-2.1.11-53.el7.centos.x86_64 (@anaconda)
libreport-filesystem = 2.1.11-53.el7.centos
Updated By: libreport-filesystem-2.1.11-53.0.3.el7.x86_64 (ol7_latest)
libreport-filesystem = 2.1.11-53.0.3.el7
Available: libreport-filesystem-2.1.11-40.0.1.el7.x86_64 (ol7_latest)
libreport-filesystem = 2.1.11-40.0.1.el7
Available: libreport-filesystem-2.1.11-42.0.1.el7.x86_64 (ol7_latest)
libreport-filesystem = 2.1.11-42.0.1.el7
Available: libreport-filesystem-2.1.11-43.0.1.el7.x86_64 (ol7_latest)
libreport-filesystem = 2.1.11-43.0.1.el7
Available: libreport-filesystem-2.1.11-53.0.1.el7.x86_64 (ol7_latest)
libreport-filesystem = 2.1.11-53.0.1.el7
Error: Package: libreport-2.1.11-53.el7.centos.i686 (base)
Requires: libreport-python = 2.1.11-53.el7.centos
Removing: libreport-python-2.1.11-53.el7.centos.x86_64 (@anaconda)
libreport-python = 2.1.11-53.el7.centos
Updated By: libreport-python-2.1.11-53.0.3.el7.x86_64 (ol7_latest)
libreport-python = 2.1.11-53.0.3.el7
Available: libreport-python-2.1.11-40.0.1.el7.x86_64 (ol7_latest)
libreport-python = 2.1.11-40.0.1.el7
Available: libreport-python-2.1.11-42.0.1.el7.x86_64 (ol7_latest)
libreport-python = 2.1.11-42.0.1.el7
Available: libreport-python-2.1.11-43.0.1.el7.x86_64 (ol7_latest)
libreport-python = 2.1.11-43.0.1.el7
Available: libreport-python-2.1.11-53.0.1.el7.x86_64 (ol7_latest)
libreport-python = 2.1.11-53.0.1.el7
Error: Package: abrt-retrace-client-2.1.11-60.el7.centos.x86_64 (@anaconda)
Requires: abrt = 2.1.11-60.el7.centos
Removing: abrt-2.1.11-60.el7.centos.x86_64 (@anaconda)
abrt = 2.1.11-60.el7.centos
Updated By: abrt-2.1.11-60.0.3.el7.x86_64 (ol7_latest)
abrt = 2.1.11-60.0.3.el7
Available: abrt-2.1.11-50.0.1.el7.x86_64 (ol7_latest)
abrt = 2.1.11-50.0.1.el7
Available: abrt-2.1.11-52.0.1.el7.x86_64 (ol7_latest)
abrt = 2.1.11-52.0.1.el7
Available: abrt-2.1.11-55.0.1.el7.x86_64 (ol7_latest)
abrt = 2.1.11-55.0.1.el7
Available: abrt-2.1.11-57.0.1.el7.x86_64 (ol7_latest)
abrt = 2.1.11-57.0.1.el7
Available: abrt-2.1.11-60.0.1.el7.x86_64 (ol7_latest)
abrt = 2.1.11-60.0.1.el7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 1 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
perl-DBD-Oracle-1.80-1.el7.x86_64 has missing requires of libclntsh.so.19.1()(64bit)```
````